# Imap message encodeing problem

Tags: email, imap, mime, quoted-printable

Some of the mails contents fetched from imap server looks like =C3=B6=C3=BC=C3=B6=C3=BC=C3=B6=C3=BC= what kind of encoding is this? Mail header encoding is UTF-8 but decoding with UTF-8 i got scrambled msg.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Quoted-Printable

It is used to transmit 8-bit data over a 7-bit medium.

Characters are converted from 8-bit to three 7-bit characters in the form `=XX` where `XX` is the hexadecimal character code for the 8-bit character, the `=` character will become `=3D`.

The length of a line is restricted to 76 characters, soft line breaks are added to  comply with this rule, this is done by ending with a `=` to indicate that the line should continue.

[https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable

[Online Decoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/quoted-printable-decoder.asp)